# Red and blue thin lines at the middle of the screen, iPhone 5

Tags: display, iphone

My phone has 4 vertical red and blue thin lines at the middle. I dropped it earlier but I only noticed it after about 4 hours because it is very thin and only visible against dark colors like black. My phone is ok but the problem started when I noticed the lines. I can't type the letters on the middle and I can't touch anything on the middle because when I do, everything just freezes

When I pressed the lock button it starts to work again but started acting up again after 1 hour or so. I pressed lock button again and it started working again until today, but i'm scared that it will happen again.

Update: When I touched the screen the lines will appear but when I'm not, the lines will fade (not totally disappearing), that's not a problem but I just want to get rid of the lines.

Update: it's been two days and the screen is still working fine

Comment: You dropped your phone.  You need to have the screen repaired.

Comment: the screen is working fine

Comment: There's no app or setting or hack that's going to fix the lines; ***the screen  is damaged.*** However, If you claim that your  "screen is  still working fine." then I fail to see the question and how we can help.

Comment: my friend has a friend who repaired it for me, he just opened my iphone and lift up the plate put this black with tape like thing properly (it is loose) and the line disappeared. still thankyou for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

1. Back up your files
2. Repair the screen

Vertical or horizontal lines are hardware failures - usually where the wires bend around the glass lcd panel. Usually the digitizer is fine after light drops, but the failure of input in regions indicates a need to replace parts and low confidence it will continue to work partially.

Comment: what will happen if i didn't replaced it? the screen is working fine i don't have any problem now just the line

Comment: If the freezing and not typing in the middle comes and goes, you might delay the repair. It's really up to you. As long as the data is backed up regularly - you can wait until it dies completely and just lose function while you look for a replacement, @jdeang